# makeing a script to change Java SDK

Tags: linux, shell-script, macintosh

I actually have the script running, but I think it's not very efficient and the only way to get it to take is to run it as "source change-java.sh"
Is there a way to get it to not have to output to a file first (I've tried everything I could google about getting a variable to an array and the only one that worked was going to a file first).

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/libexec/java_home -V 2>&1 | grep 86 | awk -F ":" '{print $1}' > java
# pattern="([0-9] [0-9])"
sed -i -e 's/[ \t]*//' java
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a newJava < java
rm java


OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=([0-9] [0-9])
newJAVA=""
while [[ $newJAVA = "" ]]; do
        echo "Select your Java version for this instance"
        select newJAVA in ${newJava[@]}; do
                if [[ $newJAVA = "" ]]; then
                        echo "Please enter a valid option. Retry."
                else {
                        export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $newJAVA` 
                        echo $JAVA_HOME
                        echo `java -version`
                }
                fi
                break
                done
        done
IFS="$OIFS"
# exit 0
```

I intend put this in .bash_profile (mac) but I'd like to get rid of it making a file before I do. Is there a way of making the change permanent? I think I'd like to give the option for it to be just for this shell or permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can replace the first 4 lines of code with:

```
read -a newJava <<<$(/usr/libexec/java_home -V 2>&1 | grep x86 | awk -F ":" '{print $1}' | xargs echo -n)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  A couple critiques of this code snippet: The `xargs echo -n` call is useless here; newlines are already trimmed out of command substitution.  Also, the `grep` and `awk` commands I can see you got from the OP, but you could accomplish the same more easily with `sed -n -e '/x86/s/:.*//p'`.

Answer (score -2):

This might do what you want: `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Comment: I appreciate the part answer.